# Re-Creating Page Objects in Playwright?

Tags: playwright, pageobjects

In Playwright (Like many other automation frameworks) you can create page objects. Using an example from Playwrights documentation: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures#without-fixtures

You have a .spec file that looks like this (The actual page object class itself can be seen above, not posting it just because it's long):

```
const { test } = require('@playwright/test');
const { TodoPage } = require('./todo-page');

test.describe('todo tests', () => {
  let todoPage;

  test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
    todoPage = new TodoPage(page);
    await todoPage.goto();
    await todoPage.addToDo('item1');
    await todoPage.addToDo('item2');
  });

  test.afterEach(async () => {
    await todoPage.removeAll();
  });

  test('should add an item', async () => {
    await todoPage.addToDo('my item');
    // ...
  });

  test('should remove an item', async () => {
    await todoPage.remove('item1');
    // ...
  });
});
```

However I wonder in such a case is there really a need to re-create the page object before each test? Wouldn't creating the page object once be good enough? (Since we would have access to all the methods/etc... and those shouldn't be changing between tests?

Is there any reason to re-create a page object for each test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`beforeAll`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-before-all) to instantiate [page object](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) so that all tests in a file can share the `page` object as todoPage is suite level variable declared outside any test.

```
test.beforeAll(async ({ page }) => {
    todoPage = new TodoPage(page);
  });
```

The Playwright Docs suggest to use as beforeEach to promote **[test isolation](https://playwright.dev/docs/browser-contexts)** so that tests can be run in parallel as they **should be** absolutely independent.

Comment: Thats sort of what I assumed you should do, so I was curious why the official docs had them as `beforeEach`

Comment: The reason playwright docs suggest that to promote test isolation so that they can also be **run in parallel**.

Comment: Thats a good point. But even with beforeAll wouldn't it still not matter? Since we aren't really doing anything besides using methods/locators (and therefore aren't really "sharing" anything between the tests)

Comment: Yes , you are "sharing" the instance of page object class which includes all its private data , methods and their state. For example- If you have a variable on class level and you change in one of the tests its value , its changed for all the other tests as well which will be running in parallel and might fail due to unexpected value.

Comment: I faced a problem where I shared an "orderID" on class level and incidentally changed that value in one of the tests and many other tests started failing for no reason. Eventually it turned out that unexpected value was causing the problem.

Comment: Good point. I guess that could happen if you are passing values to any of the methods (for filling out forms/etc...). I guess the object is destroyed at the end of each block anyways so execution time doesn't really matter anyways.

Answer (score 0):

We can create static PageObjects like:

```js
class StaticPageObject() {
  // no constructor

  static clickSomeBtn(page) {
   // now page should be feed to the PO methods
   page.locator("some-static-selector").click()
  }
}
```

With this we can use PageObject methods like:

```js
StaticPageObject.clickSomeBtn(page) // no initialization required
```

If `page` is made global (which is not a good approach), then,

```js
class StaticPageObject() {
  // no constructor

  static clickSomeBtn() {
   // now page should be feed to the PO methods
   global.page.locator("some-static-selector").click()
  }
}
```

Comment: Static methods act as global variables which in general a bad approach as they are against the core philosophy of OOP as they violate base principles like data hiding, encapsulation.

Comment: Anything can  access  and modify them without explicit object initiation.

Comment: It is true that explicit object initiation is not required for Static variables or method invocation, but they do not act as global variables or methods, but they are scoped to the class.